# Using Pillow Image.tobytes to flip the image and swap the color channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have the following code:

```py
img = Image.open('test.jpg')
texture_content = img.tobytes()
...
```

The `texture_content` contains the image upside in **RGB** format.

I want the texture_content to be flipped and to be in **BGRA** format.

How can I do this directly without using `Image.transpose` and `numpy` to swap the color channels?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [Image.tobytes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes) mentions `encoder_name='raw'` but does not explain `*args`.

Here are a couple of examples using the raw encoder:

To flip the image and swap the red and the blue channels:

```py
img.tobytes('raw', 'BGR', 0, -1)
```

To flip the image:

```py
img.tobytes('raw', 'RGB', 0, -1)
```

To swap the color channels:

```py
img.tobytes('raw', 'BGR', 0, 1)
```

To swap the color channels and add an extra channel for alpha:

```py
img.tobytes('raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
```

Unfortunately the alpha values will be `0`, to avoid this use `Image.convert` first:

```py
img.convert('RGBA').tobytes('raw', 'BGRA', 0, 1)
```

You can use [Image.frombuffer](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer) to read `texture_content` back:

Reading `texture_content`, flip the image and swap the red and the blue channels.

```py
img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', size, texture_content, 'raw', 'BGRA', 0, -1)
```